# eclipse memory analyzer doesn't open

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I installed eclipse memory analyzer (mat) and followed the tutorial 
from the official site but the .hprof file open in a standard text editor 
and not in mat as I expected.

I'm probably missing something basic, but I could not find how
to explicitly start the program. or how to configure .hprof files to open in map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should open **Memory Analysis** perspective first and then from

```
File ---> Open Heap Dump
```

you can open your .hprof file with mat.

Comment: I don't have this kind of perspective or view. 
I checked in "open perspective" and "show view"
I'm using indigo and installed both mat and mat (charts)

Comment: It is a perspective, if you don't have it, means that you have to install the mat plugin ...

Comment: Thanks!, I reinstalled the plug-in and now this perspective is available

Comment: The file wasn't being generated when I ran it from the run configurations, but once I had that saved, and ran it directly as java application , it was created-

Comment: I just installed the plugin in Eclipse Juno (with adt) through update site, restarted, and MAT doesn't appear in the perspective list. If I try to install again, it says it's already installed. Also when dump hprof it just saved but doesn't open it.  Any idea?